# Send mail on Celery task success/failure reliably

Tags: python, celery

I'm currently working on a template for bioinformatics web services using Flask and Celery. The template shows how the user can create tasks and run these on a Celery worker.

A common requirement in such services is to inform the user when a task has succeeded or failed. I'm using Flask-Mail to send mails. My first try was this:

```
@celery.task(name='app.expensive_greet', bind=True)
def expensive_greet(self, person, total, email):
    this_task_id = expensive_greet.request.id

    try:
        for i in range(total):
            time.sleep(0.1)
            self.update_state(state='PROGRESS',
                              meta={'current': i, 'total': total})

        if email:
            send_success_mail(email, this_task_id)
        return 'Greetings, {}!'.format(person)
    except SoftTimeLimitExceeded:
        if email:
            send_failure_mail(email, this_task_id)
        return 'Greetings, fallback!'
    except Exception:
        if email:
            send_failure_mail(email, this_task_id)
```

As you see there is a lot of repeated code. I wondered if it would be possible to isolate the mail handling in a custom Celery `Task` and ended up with this:

```
class MailBase(celery.Task):
    abstract = True
    def on_success(self, res, task_id, args, kwargs):
        _, _, email = args
        if email:
            send_success_mail(email, task_id)

    def on_failure(self, exc, task_id, args, kwargs, einf):
        _, _, email = args
        if email:
            send_failure_mail(email, task_id)
```

and setting `base=MailBase` for the task. I don't like this solution since:

1. It still has the repeated `if`, but I can live with that.
2. If the user changes the arguments of the task function they must also modify the `MailBase` class in two different places.
3. Unpacking of the function arguments is ugly.
4. Since this is a template for mostly non-technical users, simplicity matters.

Is there a better way to do this? Ideally I would like the mail to be metadata sent with the task, and not an argument to the task function and be able to plug in the mail functionality without touching the task itself.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to get informed when task failed, you could use celery [built-in email mechanism](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/configuration.html#conf-error-mails).

Also if you still want to insist on your own way, you could attempt to use decorator to wraps the email related operation.

```
import functools


def send_emails(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        this_task_id = self.request.id
        email = kwargs.pop('email', False)  # get email and remove it from kwargs
        try:
            ret = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
        except NotifyException as ex:
            if email:
                send_failure_mail(email, this_task_id)
            return ex.value
        except Exception:
            if email:
                send_failure_mail(email, this_task_id)
            # It would be better to raise again to allow celery knows the task has failed
            raise
        else:
            if email:
                send_success_mail(mail, this_task_id)
            return ret
    return wrapper
```

NotifyException is introduced for case when an error occurs, but the user does not treat it as a failure, just want to send an email instead.

```
class NotifyException(Exception):
    '''
    This exception would be handled by send_emails decorator, the decorator will
    catch it and return its value to outer.
    '''
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        super(NotifyException, self).__init__(value)
```

Note that it would be better to hold `email` argument in configuration file.

And now the task method will be changed like this

```
@celery.task(name='app.expensive_greet', bind=True)
@send_emails
def expensive_greet(self, person, total):
    try:
        for i in range(total):
            time.sleep(0.1)
            self.update_state(state='PROGRESS',
                              meta={'current': i, 'total': total})
        return 'Greetings, {}!'.format(person)
    except SoftTimeLimitExceeded:
        # Note that raise this exception to allow the decorator catch it
        # and return the value of the exception
        raise NotifyException('Greetings, fallback!')
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. The email must be given to the task since it changes (the user enters his email when he initiates a job on the server and expects an email when it completes/fails), so it cannot be stored in the configuration. Thus problems 1-3 are still there :)

Comment: I am not clearly understand  **The email must be given to the task since it changes**. Does that mean some of tasks might require email, but others not. If so, we could get it from **kwargs** in wrapper() of send_emails. Everything above remains.

Comment: You're right! I tried that earlier and for some reason it didn't work, so I convinced myself that Celery did not support keywords arguments.

Could your edit your answer to include this? Then I'll mark it as accepted :)

Comment: I have added a line of code **email = kwargs.pop('email', False)** within send_emails decorator. We need to specify email as keyword parameter when calling tasks, like  *expensive_greet('Tom', 3, email=True)*